# CSS: Set color to parent's background-color

Tags: css

From the image below:

[image]

How would I make the text and icons inside the white boxes be the same color as the background of the big box?

Here is how the markup looks

```
<div class="class-item blue-bg">
  <!--Heading stuff-->
  <div class="class-item-actions">
    <span class="pick-up-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-female fa-lg"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-child"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="full-day-icon blue">AM / PM</span>
    <span class="unapproved-projects-icon blue">
     2&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-th-large fa-lg fa-fw class-item-action"></i>
    </span>
    <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-lg></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

So essentially, how can I make it so somehow I don't need to add the `blue` class to `full-day-icon` and `unapproved-projects-icon`and instead it inherits the blue color from `class-item`'s `background-color`?

EDIT: Here is the relevant CSS

```
  .class-item {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.85;
  }

  .full-day-icon {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
  }

  .unapproved-projects-icon {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
  }
```

Comment: There currently isn't anyway to use a "parent" selector.  So you may need to just have both those classes set to same color through css.

Comment: Are you able to provide your css as well please?

Comment: @Mindless I added the relevant CSS

Comment: If you're not worried about compatibility with Internet Explorer, then CSS variables might be something to consider using.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's okay for you to use [CSS Variables](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), here is a neat and simple way to do this:

```
  .class-item {
    /** Specify the BG color in one place. **/
    --class-item-bg: #0076A5;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: var(--class-item-bg);
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.85;
  }

  .full-day-icon {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: white;
    color: var(--class-item-bg);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
  }

  .unapproved-projects-icon {
    background-color: white;
    color: var(--class-item-bg);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
  }
```

You can check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjppjcgf/1/) to see how you can then use JavaScript to change the property so that it affects all the CSS rules where it is used.

Comment: I like this. I have multiple `class-item`'s that should be different color but I think I can see a way to do it. I think this is the closest to what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @Robert and make sure that this feature is supported in your production environment. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit different properties in CSS. So a child div wouldn't be able to inherit the `background-color` of it's parent for it's `color` property.

```
.parent {
  background-color: red;
}
.child {
  color: inherit-background-color /* Not a way to do this without a preprocessor */
}
```

Why not just apply the styles directly?

```
  .full-day-icon {
    color: #0076A5;
  }
```

```css
.class-item {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #0076A5;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.85;
  }

  .full-day-icon {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: white;
    color: #0076A5;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
  }

  .unapproved-projects-icon {
    background-color: white;
    color: #0076A5;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="class-item blue-bg">
  <!--Heading stuff-->
  <div class="class-item-actions">
    <span class="pick-up-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-female fa-lg"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-child"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="full-day-icon blue">AM / PM</span>
    <span class="unapproved-projects-icon blue">
     2&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-th-large fa-lg fa-fw class-item-action"></i>
    </span>
    <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-lg></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want apply the styles directly because the colors are dynamic, the `#0076A5` was just the default.

Anyway, thank you for the answer.

I looked around and hoped there was some magic with `currentColor` or `transparency` that I could do or something.

Thank you!

Comment: so your dynamic code could set the same color to parent and child, couldn't it?